# Is there tool to quantify precisely how much lag Dragon NaturallySpeaking has?

Tags: speech-recognition, dragon-naturally-speaking

I have two computers. On each of them Dragon NaturallySpeaking is installed. I would like to compare the recognition lag[*] between the two computers. Is there any tool to quantify precisely how much lag Dragon NaturallySpeaking has?

[*] recognition lag = how long it takes for Dragon NaturallySpeaking to transcribe what the user said)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A German guy has created a tool for measuring various Dragon parameters a while ago. If you sign up to this forum (http://dragon-spracherkennung.forumprofi.de/topic211-testing-performance-in-dns.html) and ask nicely in English he should provide you with a download link.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a stopwatch. Start it when you stop talking and stop it when the text appears completely on the screen. Lower the time the less lag there is. If you need more accuracy, repeat this several times.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for some application that computes for me the delay between when I start to speak and when Dragon starts to write. I guess that would be a bit more precise than manually starts the stopwatch, and allows more accurate comparison between users (manual operations can lead to more subjective measures).