# How can I make voice command recognition as fast as possible in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

I have defined a couple of voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking, which I need to use very often. As a result, I would like that the latency in recognizing those voice commands to be as low as possible.

I set the "pause required before commands" to be as short as possible, i.e. 0.1 second:

[image]

I set the "speed versus accuracy" to have the fastest response possible:

[image]

I am aware that pruning the dictionary from unused words might help (FYI: [Removing all abbreviations from Dragon NaturallySpeaking's dictionary](https://superuser.com/q/836273/116475)).

What else can do to make voice command recognition as fast as possible in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Comment: What kinds of times are we talking about (what response time do you get in general and what are you now getting on those commands)?  What are your system specs?  BTW, as a PhD student in AI at MIT, you're supposed to be answering questions like this, not asking them.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Well I am still looking for [a tool to quantify precisely how much lag Dragon NaturallySpeaking has](http://superuser.com/q/697930/116475)) but I would say right now it takes around 700-800 ms from the moment I'm done saying the voice command and the command starts, which is pretty good, but I am always eager to reduce the latency :) on a laptop i7-3610QM + 16 GB RAM + SSD M500 Crucial + Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of stuff that I have found useful in the past to reduce latency. Especially on weaker systems, these measures combined can yield a noticeable reduction in latency, not only for commands, but also for standard dictation.

You already own a pretty kick-ass system and all of the below measures may improve latency only slightly. If you find that some things you want to use commands for stop working after following my recommendations, just switch the commands back on.

## Commands

Further measures you can take in the Commands tab:

- Disable all commands that you do not need, but leave the "click" commands intact because they reduce latency by reducing ambiguity.

I mostly disable for my clients the following commands because hardly anyone ever needs them:

- mouse motion
- recognition mode switching
- web & desktop search (usually unneeded)
- E-Mail and calendar
- launching from desktop and/or start menu

Under "More commands", you may also disable NLC (Natural language commands) for Word and Excel.

## Miscellaneous

- disable voice enable menus (unless needed)

## Profile settings

When creating a Dragon profile, use BestMatch IV (or even III) instead of BestMatch V. For some this may result in worse accuracy, but it may be worth it depending on your system.

## Computer-related measures

- Upgrade your PC/notebook to the fastest newest processor you can afford (make it hurt). i7 and i5 are recommended (and AMD equivalent).
- Use an SSD (you already do, I mention it just for reference).
- Close all programs you don't need while working with Dragon. Make sure you have enough RAM for all the applications that you use simultaneously.
- A note for notebook users: Make sure that a high performance setting is selected in your Windows' energy settings. Energy saving settings can affect latency massively.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Out of curiosity what latency do you manage to achieve?

Comment: I don't measure latency. I don't really care. I write my mails and such mostly without looking at the screen. Accuracy is more important to me than latency.